# Face Recognition in C# (using EigenFaceRecognizer) recognizing an unknown face as a trained face

Tags: c#, .net, face-recognition

I was trying to do face recognition in C# with "EigenFaceRecognizer". But the problem is that the Recognizer recognizes an unknown face as a known one. Once the recognizer is trained to recognize that unknown face then it recognizes that face correctly. But it never shows "Unknown" as written in the code below.

This is the full code to recognize, capture, save and train faces:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Face;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

namespace FaceRecognition
{
    class FaceRecognition:Form
    {
        private double distance = 50;
        private CascadeClassifier CascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Resources/Haarcascade/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");
        private Image<Bgr, byte> Frame = (Image<Bgr, byte>)null;
        private Capture camera;
        private Mat mat = new Mat();
        private List<Image<Gray, byte>> trainedFaces = new List<Image<Gray, byte>>();
        private List<int> PersonLabs = new List<int>();
        private bool isEnable_SaveImage = false;
        private string ImageName;
        private PictureBox PictureBox_Frame;
        private PictureBox PictureBox_smallFrame;
        private string setPersonName;
        public bool isTrained = false;
        private List<string> Names = new List<string>();
        private EigenFaceRecognizer eigenFaceRecognizer;
        private IContainer components = (IContainer)null;
        private List<String> retNames = new List<string>();

        public FaceRecgnition()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            if (Directory.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Training_Data\\Faces\\Image"))
                return;
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Training_Data\\Faces\\Image");
        }

        public void getPersonName(Control control)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_getPersonName_Tick);
            timer.Interval = 100;
            timer.Start();

            void timer_getPersonName_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) => control.Text = this.setPersonName;
        }

        public void openCamera(PictureBox pictureBox_Camera, PictureBox pictureBox_Trained)
        {
            this.PictureBox_Frame = pictureBox_Camera;
            this.PictureBox_smallFrame = pictureBox_Trained;
            this.camera = new Capture();
            this.camera.ImageGrabbed += new EventHandler(this.Camera_ImageGrabbed);
            this.camera.Start();
        }

        public void Save_IMAGE(string imageName)
        {
            this.ImageName = imageName;
            this.isEnable_SaveImage = true;
        }

        private void Camera_ImageGrabbed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.camera.Retrieve((IOutputArray)this.mat, 0);
            this.Frame = this.mat.ToImage<Bgr, byte>(false).Resize(this.PictureBox_Frame.Width, this.PictureBox_Frame.Height, (Inter)2);

            this.detectFace();
            this.PictureBox_Frame.Image = (Image)this.Frame.Bitmap;
        }

        private void detectFace()
        {
            
            
            Image<Bgr, byte> resultImage = this.Frame.Convert<Bgr, byte>();
            Mat mat = new Mat();
            CvInvoke.CvtColor((IInputArray)this.Frame, (IOutputArray)mat, (ColorConversion)6, 0);
            CvInvoke.EqualizeHist((IInputArray)mat, (IOutputArray)mat);
            Rectangle[] rectangleArray = this.CascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale((IInputArray)mat, 1.1, 4, new Size(), new Size());
            if ((uint)rectangleArray.Length > 0U)
            {
                foreach (Rectangle face in rectangleArray)
                {
                    Image<Bgr, byte> frame = this.Frame;
                    Rectangle rectangle = face;
                    Bgr bgr = new Bgr(Color.SpringGreen);
                    MCvScalar mcvScalar = ((Bgr)bgr).MCvScalar;
                    CvInvoke.Rectangle((IInputOutputArray)frame, rectangle, mcvScalar, 2, (LineType)8, 0);
                    this.SaveImage(face);
                    resultImage.ROI = face;
                    this.trainedIamge();
                    String name = this.CheckName(resultImage, face);
                    if (!retNames.Contains(name))
                    {
                        retNames.Add(name);
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                this.setPersonName = "";
                retNames.Clear();

            }

        }

        private void SaveImage(Rectangle face)
        {
            if (!this.isEnable_SaveImage)
                return;
            Image<Bgr, byte> image = this.Frame.Convert<Bgr, byte>();
            image.ROI = face;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
                {
                    ((CvArray<byte>)image.Resize(100, 100, (Inter)2)).Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Training_Data\\Faces\\Image\\" + this.ImageName + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy-hh-mm-ss") + ".jpg");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    
                }
                
                
            });
            
            this.isEnable_SaveImage = false;
            this.trainedIamge();
        }

        private void trainedIamge()
        {
            try
            {
                int num = 0;
                this.trainedFaces.Clear();
                this.PersonLabs.Clear();
                this.Names.Clear();
                foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Training_Data\\Faces\\Image", "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    
                    this.trainedFaces.Add(new Image<Gray, byte>(file));
                    this.PersonLabs.Add(num);
                    String name = file.Split('\\').Last().Split('_')[0];
                    this.Names.Add(name);
                    ++num;
                }
                this.eigenFaceRecognizer = new EigenFaceRecognizer(num, this.distance);
                ((FaceRecognizer)this.eigenFaceRecognizer).Train<Gray, byte>(this.trainedFaces.ToArray(), this.PersonLabs.ToArray());
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }


        private string CheckName(Image<Bgr, byte> resultImage, Rectangle face)
        {
            retNames.Clear();
            try
            {
                if (!this.isTrained)
                    return null;
                Image<Gray, byte> image = resultImage.Convert<Gray, byte>().Resize(100, 100, (Inter)2);
                //);
                CvInvoke.EqualizeHist((IInputArray)image, (IOutputArray)image);
                //.Predict((IInputArray)image)
                FaceRecognizer.PredictionResult predictionResult = ((FaceRecognizer)this.eigenFaceRecognizer).Predict(image);
                if (predictionResult.Label != -1 && predictionResult.Distance < 5000)
                {
                    this.PictureBox_smallFrame.Image = (Image)this.trainedFaces[(int)predictionResult.Label].Bitmap;
                    this.setPersonName = this.Names[(int)predictionResult.Label].Replace(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Training_Data\\Faces\\Image\\", "").Replace(".jpg", "");
                    Image<Bgr, byte> frame = this.Frame;
                    string setPersonName = this.setPersonName;
                    Point point = new Point(face.X - 2, face.Y - 2);
                    Bgr bgr = new Bgr(Color.Gold);
                    MCvScalar mcvScalar = ((Bgr)bgr).MCvScalar;
                    CvInvoke.PutText((IInputOutputArray)frame, setPersonName, point, (FontFace)1, 1.0, mcvScalar, 1, (LineType)8, false);
                    return setPersonName;
                }
                else
                {
                    Image<Bgr, byte> frame = this.Frame;
                    Point point = new Point(face.X - 2, face.Y - 2);
                    Bgr bgr = new Bgr(Color.OrangeRed);
                    MCvScalar mcvScalar = ((Bgr)bgr).MCvScalar;
                    CvInvoke.PutText((IInputOutputArray)frame, "Unknown", point, (FontFace)1, 1.0, mcvScalar, 1, (LineType)8, false);
                    return "Unknown";
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && this.components != null)
                this.components.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(8f, 16f);
            this.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new Size(800, 450);
            this.Name = nameof(FaceRecognition);
            this.Text = nameof(FaceRecognition);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        public List<String> getRetNames { get => retNames; }
        private String setRetNames { set => retNames.Add(value); }
    }
}
```

This is the main piece of the code (If you are in hurry) where it recognizes the face:-

```
private string CheckName(Image<Bgr, byte> resultImage, Rectangle face)
    {
        retNames.Clear();
        try
        {
            if (!this.isTrained)
                return null;
            Image<Gray, byte> image = resultImage.Convert<Gray, byte>().Resize(100, 100, (Inter)2);
         
            CvInvoke.EqualizeHist((IInputArray)image, (IOutputArray)image);

            FaceRecognizer.PredictionResult predictionResult = ((FaceRecognizer)this.eigenFaceRecognizer).Predict((IInputArray)image);
            if (predictionResult.Label != -1 && predictionResult.Distance < 5000)
            {
                this.PictureBox_smallFrame.Image = (Image)this.trainedFaces[(int)predictionResult.Label].Bitmap;
                this.setPersonName = this.Names[(int)predictionResult.Label].Replace(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Training_Data\\Faces\\Image\\", "").Replace(".jpg", "");
                Image<Bgr, byte> frame = this.Frame;
                string setPersonName = this.setPersonName;
                Point point = new Point(face.X - 2, face.Y - 2);
                Bgr bgr = new Bgr(Color.Gold);
                MCvScalar mcvScalar = ((Bgr)bgr).MCvScalar;
                CvInvoke.PutText((IInputOutputArray)frame, setPersonName, point, (FontFace)1, 1.0, mcvScalar, 1, (LineType)8, false);
                return setPersonName;
            }
            else
            {
                Image<Bgr, byte> frame = this.Frame;
                Point point = new Point(face.X - 2, face.Y - 2);
                Bgr bgr = new Bgr(Color.OrangeRed);
                MCvScalar mcvScalar = ((Bgr)bgr).MCvScalar;
                CvInvoke.PutText((IInputOutputArray)frame, "Unknown", point, (FontFace)1, 1.0, mcvScalar, 1, (LineType)8, false);
                return "Unknown";
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now no matter which face it is, --`FaceRecognizer.PredictionResult predictionResult = ((FaceRecognizer)this.eigenFaceRecognizer).Predict((IInputArray)image);` always returns `predictionResult.Label = 0` and `predictionResult.Distance = 0`.

**What I tried :-**

- Changing `private double distance = 50;`. Initially it was 1E+19, then I made it 5000, 2000 and tweaked it with many different values.
- Using all the CascadeClassifier xml files.

But at all the instances of me doing something to fix the problem the values of `predictionResult.Label` and `predictionResult.Distance` were always "0".

**P.S :- This question can be a duplicate of 1 or 2 questions but in those questions neither there was sufficient information provided by the questioner nor there is an answer.**

Answer (score 0):

I had a smiliar problem. What fixed it for me was to make sure that

1. your labels do not contain a zero. 0 is for errors or similar.
2. Get a public image dataset and train your type "unknown" on that.
   This is what i used: http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/projects/CelebA.html

Then Eigen will recognize unknown faces as unknown most of the time.